# Norm of a $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-algebra is surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $n$ be positive integer and $R = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ be the ring of integer of a quadratic number field where $\alpha$ is the root of the quadratic polynomial $X^2 -uX + v \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$, such that $disc(R)$ is prime to $n$ and that every prime $p$ which divides $n$ is inert in $R$. Let $A = (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})[\alpha]$. We have the norm map :

$$
N : A \to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \;\;\;\;\;\; y = a +b\alpha \mapsto y\overline{y} = (a+b\alpha)(a + b(u-\alpha))
$$

**My question is :** is the norm map surjective when we consider the restriction $N : A^\times \to (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ ? If so how do you prove it ? If not do you have a counter example ?

**Edit : (false)**  Ok so here is what I got from Serre's book as suggested by Jiangwei. $R_p/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is a quadratic extension of unramified local fields and since the norm is surjective for the residue field (because they are finite field) we have $[\mathbb{Q}_p^\times : N(K_p^\times)] = [K_p :\mathbb{Q}_p] = 2$. Somehow I feel this implies that the norm (in my case) isn't always surjective because if it was then it would also be true for the completion. I'm not sure how to prove that so if anyone was kind enough to give a precise argument that would be great.

**Edit :** Forget the previous edit it's completely false. In fact there is a theorem which says that if $L/K$ is a unramified extension local field then the norm map $N : \mathcal{O}_L^\times \to \mathcal{O}_K^\times$ is surjective which then obviously implies the result I was looking for. The proof of the result on local fields can for example be found [here, page 9 in the proof of lemma 5.2](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ty245/Yoshida_2008_lcftfinal.pdf%20%22here,%20%20page%209,%20in%20the%20proof%20of%20lemma%205.2%C3%A9)

Comment: By the Chinese reminder theorem, it is enough to consider the case $n=p^r$ is a prime power.  To consider all $r$ at once, we are reduced to the case of local fields.  The answer now is given in Sect V.2 of "Local fields" by J.-P. Serre.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will look it up.

Comment: But won't you then have, more precisely, $N(K_p^\times)=\langle p^2\rangle \times \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$? In other words, representatives of all the non-trivial residue classes modulo $p$ will be in the image of the norm?

Comment: I don't really understand your remark, would you consider expand in an answer ? Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: Hello,
The link you posted no longer works.  Please post a more permanent reference.  A title is usually enough to find something via Google.  Thanks.